# How to style elements in the controller using Webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am styling `app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb` in `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss` using Webpacker and I want to style `app/views/pages/home.html.erb` in `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss` as well but I am not sure why it is not working, I have checked around for resources but I didn't find one that works, perhaps someone know about this? This is the file structure:

```
app
 |_ assets
    |_ stylesheets
       |_ pages.scss
 |_ javascript
    |_ stylesheets
       |_ application.scss
 |_ views
    |_ layouts
       |_ _navigation.html.erb
    |_ pages
       |_ home.html.erb
```

This is the code in `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss` and `#home-container` is from the `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`:

```
@use "bootstrap";

.navbar {
  background-color: black !important;
}

.nav-link {
  color: white !important;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#home-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Thanks ya. A beginner learning Ruby on Rails.

Comment: In Rails you rarely do stylesheets per view/controller, instead you just have one single manifest thats loaded through your `application.html.erb`. Its just not viable approach with turbolinks/turbo involved. I would argue that thinking of your css in terms of "pages" (I want this doodad on page X to look like Y) is an antipattern in itself.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, would you please explain in simple terms thanks ya